# Measure to compare other table values

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables A&B and I created two measures to find sales of both tables 1&2. When I use the matrix visual to see the values of both tables by using measures, Its showing correct values as per date hierarchy.

But, when I use the 2nd measure of table-b in table-a matrix visual its showing the subtotal values but not as per hierarchy.

I have a requirement to show the measure of table-B in visual 1 which contains table-a regions and date along with measure1 to compare the measure 1&2 in single visual as per hierarchy.

For Visual 1(matrix) - used columns: Region column from table A, date column from date table, measure1

For Visual 2(matrix) - used columns: Region column from table B, date column from date table,measure2

Table A, Table B,Date table : by using date as common column b/w date and table a& b form the 1 to many relationship.

Requirement: formula of measure 2: sum(sales), Its splitting the values as per hierarchy when I use it 2nd visual. I want to see the same in 1st visual, it contains same date column & region for table-A

Can anyone help me to how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

when I use the 2nd measure of table-b in table-a matrix visual <- This means that you don't have a dimension table that contains information for both a and b. In order to be able to split it, it needs to have the same 'reference', so it knows what date is used for calculating.